# package keyval error: bibtex8 undefined

Tags: biblatex

I'm using [this CV template](http://robjhyndman.com/research/cv.sty) and it was working fine in the past. But now the same file gives the following error:

> package keyval error: bibtex8 undefined

I tried the following two different codes:

```
\usepackage[
        sorting=ynt
    , bibstyle=authoryear-comp
    , labelyear=false
    , defernumbers=true
    , maxnames=20
    , firstinits=true
    , uniquename=init
    , dashed=false
     ]{biblatex}
```

and

```
\usepackage[
    sorting=ynt
, bibstyle=authoryear-comp
, labelyear=false
, defernumbers=true
, maxnames=20
, firstinits=true
, uniquename=init
, dashed=false
, backend = bibtex8
 ]{biblatex}
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `bibtex` as the option for `backend`, and then run `bibtex8` instead of `bibtex`?

Comment: I get no errors. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Is your distribution up to date?

Comment: Thanks @Guido for your comment. Can you explain your comment in detail? Thanks

Comment: According to the `biblatex` manual `biblatex` does not know whether one runs `bibtex` or `bibtex8`.  The differences between `bibtex8` and `bibtex` (beside memory) are on sorting (mix-case sorting is allowed in `bibtex8`) and handling of non-ASCII characters. The other option is to check whether you distribution is up to date (and eventually you can have a go with `biber`).

Comment: @MYaseen208 Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and see what the resulting `File List` in the log says? I wonder what version of `biblatex` you have installed.

Comment: Thanks @JosephWright for showing interest in solving my problem. I just updated packages and following you advise I found the following information about `biblatex` in log file: Package: `biblatex 2013/01/10 v2.5 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)`. Any guidance will be highly appreciated (I'm not expert in `LaTex`). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are giving

```
\usepackage[bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

instead of the required

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
```

as `bibtex8` is a *value* for the `backend` key and not a key in its own right.

A full example which works fine for me:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

and gives file list

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
biblatex.sty    2013/01/10 v2.5 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex1.sty    2013/01/10 v2.5 programmable bibliographies (bibtex) (PK/JW/AB
)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
blx-compat.def    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 english.lbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
 ***********
```

Comment: Even using `\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}` throws the same error.

Comment: I'm using this [cv template](http://robjhyndman.com/research/cv.sty).

Comment: @MYaseen208 Please try my MWE and compare your file list to mine, then report back.

Comment: Every item my file list exactly matches with yours. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: @MYaseen208 In that case something odd is going on: can you e-mail me your `.log` file (joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk)

Comment: Did you get my email? @joseph